# 40f equal to 40 pixel?

Tags: c#, xna

I want that my character makes a 40 pixel height jump if I press the A button once. But I don't know if 40f is equal to 40 pixel?
What do you think about my code? What is wrong?
In addition, I want that my program runs with the same speed on every computer.

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
Texture2D image, water;
float Gravity = 5.0F;
float Acceleration = 20.0F;
Vector2 Position = new Vector2(1200,720);
Vector2 Velocity;
float rotation = 0;
SpriteEffects flip;
Vector2 Speed = new Vector2(0, 0);

public Game1()
{
    graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
    Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1280;
    graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 720;
}

protected override void Initialize()
{
    base.Initialize();
}

protected override void LoadContent()
{   
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
    image = Content.Load<Texture2D>("cartoondolphin");
    water = Content.Load<Texture2D>("background");
    flip = SpriteEffects.None;
}

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    float VelocityX = 0f;
    float VelocityY = 0f;

    float time = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
    KeyboardState kbState = Keyboard.GetState();
    if(kbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left)) 
    {
        rotation = 0;
        flip = SpriteEffects.None;
        VelocityX += -5f;
    } 

    if(kbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right)) 
    {
        rotation = 0;
        flip = SpriteEffects.FlipHorizontally;
        VelocityX += 5f;
    } 

    // jump if the dolphin is under water
    if(Position.Y >= 670)
    {
        if (kbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
        {     
            if (flip == SpriteEffects.None)
            { 
              VelocityY += 40f;
            }
            else
            { 
              VelocityY += 40f;
            }
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        VelocityY += -10f;
    }

    float deltaY = 0;
    float deltaX = 0;

    deltaY = Gravity * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

    deltaX += VelocityX * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds * Acceleration;
    deltaY += -VelocityY * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds * Acceleration;

    Speed = new Vector2(Speed.X + deltaX, Speed.Y + deltaY);

    Position += Speed * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

    Velocity.X = 0;

    if (Position.Y + image.Height/2 > graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight)
        Position.Y = graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight - image.Height/2;

    base.Update(gameTime);
}

protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
    spriteBatch.Begin();
    spriteBatch.Draw(water, new Rectangle(0, graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight -100, graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth, 100), Color.White);
    spriteBatch.Draw(image, Position, null, Color.White, MathHelper.ToRadians(rotation), new Vector2(image.Width / 2, image.Height / 2), 1, flip, 1);
    spriteBatch.End();           

    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having with the code? If you want somebody to simply review it, I suggest taking the question to codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: If you have `40f` in your code, it just means that the number 40 treated as a floating point number. So that is similar to writing 40.0, the number stays the same - but it is now clear that it can also be a non-integer number (e.g. 40.5). If your `VelocityY` is in pixels, then adding `40f` will change that by 40 pixels (per iteration/update).

Comment: I'd presume that the units are pixels, since it'd seem like the least arbitrary unit of length to use here, but I don't entirely understand the question.

Comment: 40f equal to 40 pixel? Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're not taking the `gameTime` into account.  If a computer with a fast CPU executes that code twice as fast as a slower PC, the value of velocity will increase twice as fast (relative to the slower PC).

When you have code like:

```
VelocityX += 5f;
```

You need to keep track of the last `gameTime`, and get the difference between the frames, and multiply that by your constant. (Some code grabbed from [Xna adding gravity to a 2d sprite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916168/xna-adding-gravity-to-a-2d-sprite))

```
int updateTime = gt.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds - oldgt.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;

float timeScalar = updateTime / AVG_FRAME_TIME;

VelocityX += 5f * timeScalar;
```